# Why did my pound cake turn out dry?

Tags: cake

I baked a pound cake in an enamel glazed fluted pan and it turned out dry. Was it the pan or what could it be?  I followed the recipe. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Does it have something to do with the heat ? But how and why ?

Comment: Can you tell us how long you baked it and what temperature?

Comment: Even if you followed the recipe, that doesn't mean the recipe is not the problem. If possible, please post the recipe, or a link to it. Also, how sure are you that the oven temp is correct? Have you tried using a oven thermometer? If not, why? Lastly, were all of the ingredients within the dates listed for their self-life?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried baking it for a shorter amount of time? Cakes become dry if they are baked for too long. if you use a tooth pick, it should not come out clean, but with crumbles attached. 
Clean = dry. 
Crumbles = moist and done.
wet = not baked enough

Answer (score 3):

It is most probably because of recipe.  If a recipe is off balance with its ratio of dry and wet ingredients this is a main cause of baking failures.

In cakes there are generally four main ingredients which are flour, eggs, sugar and fat. 
Whilst flour and eggs are the major structure-builders, sugar and fat actually soften the cake's structure by providing moisture. If you have too much of the structure-building flour and eggs, the cake will be tough and dry. If you have too much of fats and sugars, the cake might not set and probably will collapse. Therefore the ratio of these four main ingredients are really important.

For pound cakes ideal ratio is `1:1:1:1` ratio. Which is also known as `flour=sugar | egg=butter` rule as well. This means flour and sugar should be equal in weight (not in volume) and eggs and butter should be equal in weight as well.

Although you  have the ratio and your cake is still dry I suggest you to improve softeners (fat or sugar). Another good alternative is to use liquid oils such as sunflower oil instead of butter.

Good luck for your future cakes..

Answer (score 0):

I have found, in my many years of baking, that simple over baking is the major cause of of a dry pound cake, I always decrease the baking time from a recipe for at least 15- 20 minutes.

Comment: Not sure this works as general advice. What temperature oven and how much batter are you baking in that case? I guess reducing the baking time for a 2lb recipe that specifies 325°F for an hour by 15mins would be OK provided you test for doneness.